# What is a code reuse attack?

Tags: security, code-reuse

What is a code reuse attack, and how can we defend against them? I'd love an example.

I don't understand how a reuse attack is significantly different from a buffer overflow attack.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Buffer overflow is a _vulnerability_ (problem in your code) that allows code reuse, code inject or other attacks (the used technique).

Comment: @t.niese So would a return to lib-c attack be a form of code reuse?

Comment: If you don't use a way to rewirte code in memory (code injection) but change the control flow using e.g. a buffer overflow to use existing code in a different way as intended, then it is code reuse. Return to clib does not change existing code, but manipulates the stack so it is code reuse.

Answer (score 6):

It is a technique of exploitation which relies on executing the code which is already present in the memory (e.g. as part of the standard library) instead of shipping it to the attacked host as part of the payload.  This significantly complicates the job of the attack mitigation software since the surface area of the attack shrinks and makes it much harder to detect (e.g. by fingerprinting) and distinguish from the legitimate traffic.
Here is the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming

Comment: What do you mean by "the standard library"? If you're not using any of your own code--what real damage could you do?

Comment: you are piecing together fragments of the library code to do wht you want.

Answer (score 1):

Code reuse attack uses a vulnerability like buffer overflow, memory leak etc. With the help of these vulnerabilities, an adversary uploads a malicious payload to victim machine to hijack control flow or attack to other systems. Code reuse attack uses Return Oriented Programming or Jump oriented Programming. This attack comes from either by stack or heap by using data cache.